# Passive Root Usage Program/File Type

Tags: permissions, root

As opposed to my previous phrasing asking quite simply ***Fastest Way to Give a Virus to Ubuntu?***, this is re-phrasing it into a question that it inside the boundaries of the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). I would like to know if there is a file type, or even a program that can perform a root operation without input of the user. For example, when any change is made to `/usr/bin` the user is asked to input the root password, and that is (usually) only known by them/the person that installed Ubuntu. However, I have seen questions on [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com)
 concerning viruses that simply wait for the user to use terminal for root need, and record the keystroke. Is this possible? I do not want to know any specific virus examples or even how to do this, I would just like to know IF a program or file like this exists or can exist. Thank you, David!

Comment: This belongs with "Information Security" : http://security.stackexchange.com/
Please move it there!

Comment: @KenMollerup I disagree 100%. This is about any file on the Ubuntu system that can function without a user input, that could give Ubuntu a virus. This relates to Ubuntu more than it does to security in general. I want to know FILE TYPES, that could potentially be virus causing

Comment: Yes Have you seen what they do at "Information Security" and there are a lot of Ubuntu here - Viruses malvare worms etc...
They know!

Comment: This question is off-topic because **no such advice** should be given (on this forum) on techniques to circumvent security measures against *code injection, remote-code execution, or portable code* that are embedded within the Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this question in reality, it can be done, but not passively. Over time, Ubuntu and Linux in general have become more secure, to prevent viruses. The site found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus) explains most Trojans, Viruses, and Worms that can and have affected Ubuntu. This site is updated to even the most recent, because as you said, viruses today are mostly designed for Windows and Mac OS X. Giving Ubuntu a virus is possible, but it really isn't worth the work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major categories of how a virus can infect a system:

#### Exploiting Bugs

One way a virus can infect a system is to exploit bugs. Assume a system has all sorts of security in place, but if you do x, y and z in sequence (a sequence unforeseen to be problematic), you can run a piece of code as root.

This kind of virus can be a serious treat. However, there can never be a permanent answer to your question regarding this. Any answer for this type of virus to your question would be describing an exploitable bug, which end up being quickly fixed, patched and made unexploitable.

We don't see this kind of virus on Linux mainly for two reasons:

- Hackers labor to find a bug in a system, and feel great when they do. In case of windows, there is not much to do but exploit the bug and write a virus. In case of Linux, they can send a patch to fix the bug and get additionally rewarded by fame. If you follow the news, you occasionally hear of a team of researches finding an exploit in some free software (not just Linux, e.g. [heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/)) and getting it fixed, but you never hear about a hacker finding an exploit in windows, even though the shear number of windows viruses show these bugs are numerous.
- GNU/Linux distributions generally have excellent package managers. All software is often updated and bugs are squashed quickly. On windows, many tech-non-savvy users may just disable updates due to how annoying it's done (Did you restart yet? Did you restart yet? Did you restart yet? Shutting down, wait indefinitely please), and even if they don't, updates only come for the core of windows and nothing else. Any virus exploiting this kind of bug has a higher chance of living for a long time on windows, and thus spreading farther.

#### Exploiting Users

Another way a virus can infect a system is to fool a user into doing it. Download some application off the internet, run it and you bring the virus upon yourself. GNU/Linux distributions use package managers which make sure the executables are those built from source by trusted packagers, and unless a packager is malicious, prevents any virus from leaking in. On windows, you have to download each application from a different website, some of which don't offer HTTPS, nor a hash of the executable. There are so many ways a virus can get through this way, and we know they do.

However, this by itself would not be so problematic, if it weren't for the user having root access. On windows, this is generally the default: the first (and usually only) user has administrative rights. It's like logging in as root on Linux. On Linux however, you are prompted to enter root passwords for anything that touches your applications (residing e.g. in `/usr/bin`), and so no virus can really "sneak in" without your notice.

With this kind of virus, the answer to your question would be to write a virus that is not open-source, asks for root permission under the pretext of doing something else, then convince a large number of people that they need this application available only in binary and give it root permission.

That's essentially not a virus anymore. It might have as well been "instructions to format your hard disk" given to people who don't know anything.

---

The most successful of bugs are those that exploit both the bugs and users. Imagine how easy it is on windows:

1. Take application X that opens files of type Y. Make sure the application cannot update itself (given how poorly software updates are supported on windows (they are not), it's very easy to find applications that don't come with an updater). You can even make it easier and go with something open-source, for example inkscape.
2. Find an bug in the application that can allow you to execute code. For example a buffer overflow, which makes it even possible to open a non-executable file such as an image and still be able to take control of the software.
3. Spread your virus to everything you can, since you likely have root access to everything. This includes the buggy software itself, so that it can automatically infect future files, or even to make sure the software would never be able to update itself.
4. The virus would eventually get detected, but given that the buggy software is never updated, continues to roam.

Now compare the situation to Linux. The bug you find may not live long as the buggy software gets patched and updated as soon as the virus is found. Moreover, even if you do get hold of the software, the most damage you can do is infect the user files, and not the system files. In the example of viruses attached to images, the software itself would not be able to get infected and the only method of transfer would be of the image itself by the user. This doesn't mean the virus cannot exist, but that it would be considerably weak and boring. No one would boast having written a boring virus.